# визуализация траектории объекта: как добавить текст к точкам на графике

Tags: python, matplotlib

Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить подписи к меткам на траектории. Имеются данные с координатами буя и соответствующая им дата. На рисунке нужно указать даты обозначенных точек.

```
x,y=lon[1:],lat[1:]
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.set_extent((27.0, 42.0, 40.8, 47.5))
ax.add_feature(LAND)
ax.add_feature(OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.coastlines('50m')
ax.plot(x,y,'b-', transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), marker='o', markevery=10)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы можете привести пример данных?

Comment: @MaxU файл .csv: дата время, долгота, широта
03.07.2006 0:58,32.529,44.008
03.07.2006 3:13,32.51,44.012
03.07.2006 4:50,32.506,44.008
03.07.2006 12:26,32.473,44.01
Дату считываю как
    dates = np.loadtxt('e:/Drifter/40414_2006.csv', delimiter=",", converters={0:lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf8"),'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'),1:np.float64}, dtype= datetime,skiprows=1,usecols=(0,))

Comment: @Olga: не добавляйте необходимую для ответа информацию в комментарии. Вместо этого в ваш вопрос информацию добавьте (с форматированием). Нажмите кнопку [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался модулем Pandas:

Пусть у нас есть `filename='/path/to/file.csv'`:

```
ts,lon,lat
03.07.2006 0:58,32.529,44.008
03.07.2006 3:13,32.51,44.012
03.07.2006 4:50,32.506,44.008
03.07.2006 12:26,32.473,44.01
```

читаем файл:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', parse_dates=['ts'])
```

получим:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
                   ts     lon     lat
0 2006-03-07 00:58:00  32.529  44.008
1 2006-03-07 03:13:00  32.510  44.012
2 2006-03-07 04:50:00  32.506  44.008
3 2006-03-07 12:26:00  32.473  44.010
```

рисуем точки:

```
In [38]: ax = df.plot.scatter(x='lon', y='lat')
```

добавляем надписи:

```
In [39]: df.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(x.ts, (x.lon, x.lat)), axis=1)
Out[39]:
0    Annotation(32.529,44.008,'2006-03-07 00:58:00')
1     Annotation(32.51,44.012,'2006-03-07 03:13:00')
2    Annotation(32.506,44.008,'2006-03-07 04:50:00')
3     Annotation(32.473,44.01,'2006-03-07 12:26:00')
dtype: object
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS Вам надо будет подумать как отформатировать дату и время, чтобы они занимали меньше места и о том как уместить эти надписи на графике...

Answer (score 1):

В **matplotlib**  текст рисуется так:

```
ax.text(x, y, r'an equation: $E=mc^2$', fontsize=15)
```

[Источник](https://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html)

Comment: возможно здесь ещё `ax.annotate()`  попробовать.